# angular-slidezilla: <slider> not showing in site

Tags: angularjs

I tried intgrating [angular-slidezilla](https://github.com/itslenny/angular-slidezilla/tree/master/src) into a web site, but the slider elements do not show.

Observations:

- I copied the .js file into the /lib folder and the .css into the /css folder.
- the site uses requirejs; I added the source file into the requirements list.
- I added the css as a stylesheet link next to the other css files in the index.html file.
- To test, I copied the demo page (the entire  part) into my HTML page and added $scope.slider1.val etc. variables to the AngularJS controller object. I also added a function which periodically changes the value of the scope variables.
- When I deploy the site and load the page, I see the values changing every second (these are shown as text near the sliders). But the sliders themselves do not show.
- "Inspect element" function shows a generated piece of DOM (div objects related to the slider), but the slider itself has size 0px*0px.
- No errors in javascript console.

Can anyone give me a hint how to investigate further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. The javascript code in `angular-slidezilla.js` was never executed. As a result the widgets were not initialized and remained in their initial hidden state.

I needed to edit one line of javascript code to get it working:

```
// app.js
var app = angular.module("app", ['ui.bootstrap', ..., 'angular-slidezilla']);
```